# Laravel 5 - authentication with custom users table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

So I have built an API in laravel and the time has come to authenticate. I have installed https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth and have created a signin route that hits this method:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    // grab credentials from the request
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

The problem here is that even though I have given JWTAuth::attempt the correct credentials it still says that they are invalid. When I look at the queries being called it passes through my email and password directly and searches for the user that way. This obviously will not work because I do not use plain text passwords. So I hashed up my password the same way the old database did it and still no good because the hash is a one way hash that will be different every time.

TL;DR;

Expected Event: JWTAuth::attempt gets a user using email and checks the returned encrypted password vs the password given and returns the token

Actual Event: JWTAuth::attempt tries to grab the user using both email and password and fails to retrieve a user since I am not storing plaintext passwords. This then triggers an invalid credentials response

Comment: Here is an idea on where you can start . https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/5.2/authentication.md You can manually check the credentials since you're using a different system and then login the use with Auth::login($user)

Comment: @CanCelik I updated my question. I obviously have looked into laravel docs but they mostly cover how to use their built in authentication with very little documentation on how any of it works or how to customize it. Since I need to do a bit of customization to handle my inherited users database this isn't much help.

Comment: @BillGarrison have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @BillGarrisonhow do you solve it?

Comment: Honestly this was 2 1/2 years ago. Usually if I find an answer I post it here as an answer so if I didn't it usually means I side stepped the issue or went with another solution. I re-read my issue but its not jogging my memories free.